# Typescript Map key auto complete

Tags: typescript

how do I make a Map which it's keys are auto complete when you try get the key.

Like:

```
const map: Map<string, string> = new Map();
map.set("key1", "value");
map.get(/* auto complete key here */)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yoy can use `type` keyword to create your own custom types, use a bar to make it a union type allowing it to accept multiple different values like the following example

```
type Key = 'key1' | 'key2';

let map = new Map<Key, string>();

map.get();
```

[image]

Code example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAIDStLwLzwOQGsUEZN4AfLXSAJkwG5RQAbWceAWwENp14A7WAd3gCy7ADzJIAGngBncACcAllwDmAPgAUAShpgQbaADoljNTnyYtQA).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an enum as `key` in the map to make it auto-complete.

```
enum Key {
    Number = 1,
    Float = 2
}

let map = new Map<Key, string>();

map.get(Key.Float);
```

Playground link: [Click here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA0sCeUDeBYAUFTUBykBGwATlALxQCMANOllAGIA2A9gIYAupUATOgL7roGwDhBYAHTiGAB3KAFlxAHjjxKUAM5tCASxABzAHwAKAJQBuAWlFiAdHuFGVNxqzbmgA)

Comment: I kind of want it to be a string and not enums.

Comment: Other way to create a type and assign values like type a = 'abc' | 'xyz' .